# does python PEX format support c extensions?

Tags: python, deployment, package

Can the format be used to deliver apps with the C extensions too?
Eggs (zip) cannot do that AFAIK.

http://pex.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Eggs *can* and *do* include C extensions. Eggs are a binary distribution format.

Comment: See the [Pillow 2.6.1 PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.6.1) for example, the `.egg` links all have a *platform* identifier. The downside is that these eggs cannot capture the UCS2 / UCS4 distinction in Python 2 builds and that matters if the C extension must handle Unicode strings.

Comment: I just discovered how it works with C extensions in PEX. I was afraid, that you can't distribute ZIPped version of C modules. PEX extracts eggs/wheels to ~/.pex folder on the target machine, thus achieving presence on the fileystem, not in ZIP file.